# CSS styling doesn't appear to have any effect

Tags: html, css

I'm working through some challenges on freeCodeCamp. Specifically, the challenge is to make a brief "tribute page" on a topic of your choice. I've been working in CodePen, but have started using Brackets because it seems more user-friendly.

My issue is that my CSS styling isn't doing anything in my standalone html file, whereas in CodePen it was working. I'm sure I'm making a boneheaded error somewhere. 
Thoughts? Thank you for any suggestions/help!

Code:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
    <style>
        .center {
            margin: auto;
        }
        
    </style>
        
    </head>
    
    <body>
    <div class="container">
      <div class="jumbotron" style="margin-top:20px" >
      <h1 style="color: black" class="text-center">Gord Downie</h1>
      <div class="row center">
        <img src="http://i.huffpost.com/gen/4541188/thumbs/o-GORD-DOWNIE-TRAGICALLY-HIP-570.jpg?5" class="center">
      </div>    
          <p class="caption text-center">  "He Who Walks Among The Stars" </p>


        <p class="text-center"> Gord Downie is a Canadian musician, most well known for his role as the lead singer of the Tragically Hip. More recently in his career, he has also been a spokesperson for the welfare of First Nations communities across Canada. Since 2016, Gord has been battling incurable brain cancer, but has been able to continue writing and performing. As a true artist, Gord has never let fame change him, always maintaining his focus on his music and philanthropy.</p>
        <div class="text-center">
            <h3 class="text-center"> <strong>Musical Works </strong></h3>
            <h5>As a member of the Tragically Hip:</h5>

            <ul class="text-center">
                <li>The Tragically Hip (Self-Titled) - <em>1987</em></li>
                <li>Up To Here - <em>1989</em></li>
                <li>Road Apples - <em>1991</em></li>
                <li>Fully Completely - <em>1992</em></li>
                <li>Day for Night - <em>1994</em></li>
                <li>Trouble at the Henhouse - <em>1996</em></li>
                <li>Phantom Power - <em>1998</em></li>
                <li>Music @ Work - <em>2000</em></li>
                <li>In Violet Light - <em>2002</em></li>
                <li>In Between Evolution - <em>2004</em></li>
                <li>World Container - <em>2006</em></li>
                <li>We Are the Same - <em>2009</em></li>
                <li>Now for Plan A - <em>2012</em></li>
            </ul>

            <h5>Solo Work</h5>
            <ul>
              <li>Coke Machine Glow - <em>2001</em></li>
              <li>Battle of the Nudes - <em>2003</em></li>
              <li>The Grand Bounce - <em>2010</em></li>
              <li>Secret Path - <em>2016</em></li>
            </ul>
          </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

Looks like you're using bootstrap classes, so you need to add the bootstrap stylesheet to your page. You can use this CDN link I've put in the HTML, or you can download the files and upload them to your site/project https://getbootstrap.com/.

Bootstrap was likely baked in to your codepen project, but bootstrap isn't a fundamental part of HTML or CSS, so if you want to use it on a custom project, you have to include it. You also want to include the bootstrap stylesheet before any of your own styles, so that the base bootstrap styles are applied, then you can overwrite specific ones if needed with styles that are loaded afterward and bootstrap won't interfere.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
    <link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <style>
        .center {
            margin: auto;
        }
        
    </style>
        
    </head>
    
    <body>
    <div class="container">
      <div class="jumbotron" style="margin-top:20px" >
      <h1 style="color: black" class="text-center">Gord Downie</h1>
      <div class="row center">
        <img src="http://i.huffpost.com/gen/4541188/thumbs/o-GORD-DOWNIE-TRAGICALLY-HIP-570.jpg?5" class="center">
      </div>    
          <p class="caption text-center">  "He Who Walks Among The Stars" </p>


        <p class="text-center"> Gord Downie is a Canadian musician, most well known for his role as the lead singer of the Tragically Hip. More recently in his career, he has also been a spokesperson for the welfare of First Nations communities across Canada. Since 2016, Gord has been battling incurable brain cancer, but has been able to continue writing and performing. As a true artist, Gord has never let fame change him, always maintaining his focus on his music and philanthropy.</p>
        <div class="text-center">
            <h3 class="text-center"> <strong>Musical Works </strong></h3>
            <h5>As a member of the Tragically Hip:</h5>

            <ul class="text-center">
                <li>The Tragically Hip (Self-Titled) - <em>1987</em></li>
                <li>Up To Here - <em>1989</em></li>
                <li>Road Apples - <em>1991</em></li>
                <li>Fully Completely - <em>1992</em></li>
                <li>Day for Night - <em>1994</em></li>
                <li>Trouble at the Henhouse - <em>1996</em></li>
                <li>Phantom Power - <em>1998</em></li>
                <li>Music @ Work - <em>2000</em></li>
                <li>In Violet Light - <em>2002</em></li>
                <li>In Between Evolution - <em>2004</em></li>
                <li>World Container - <em>2006</em></li>
                <li>We Are the Same - <em>2009</em></li>
                <li>Now for Plan A - <em>2012</em></li>
            </ul>

            <h5>Solo Work</h5>
            <ul>
              <li>Coke Machine Glow - <em>2001</em></li>
              <li>Battle of the Nudes - <em>2003</em></li>
              <li>The Grand Bounce - <em>2010</em></li>
              <li>Secret Path - <em>2016</em></li>
            </ul>
          </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Weird. It looks like its working in code preview on this page, but still not when I open page through Chrome.

Comment: Can you provide a link to see it in Chrome? @eldutcho

Comment: Apologies if this is a stupid answer - I'm not actually hosting it anywhere, what would be the best way to do this?

Comment: @eldutcho you should download bootstrap and refer to the local files then. Or just put a webserver on your computer. It's not very difficult. Mac's have webservers built in, but there is also WAMP, MAMP, and others. You can also setup a free site using github pages.

Answer (score 0):

This sounds a bit obvious but:

Do check that you've included your `CSS` file:

Example for bootstrap CDN:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
 <!-- load bootstrap from CDN !-->   
 <link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
           
    </head>
    <body>
    Content
    </body>
</html>
```

Secondly why use `<style>` tags? you could also include that in another file.

Comment: If I'm only using CSS internally in my <style> tags, do I still need to link somewhere? I have included bootstrap link and it still seems to do nothing in preview/opening file directly through Chrome.

Comment: No, normally it shouldn't be a problem. Inline style tags are bad practice. That's all. And are u previewing it or running it through a localhost like WAMP or XAMPP? @eldutcho

Comment: That's good info as well. These online code camps are good for throwing you into things, but don't take much time to go over best practices/industry standards.
I'm simply using the Live Preview feature in Brackets, which opens the file in Chrome browser.

Comment: @eldutcho it's pretty easy to put it into a localhost environment and to try it out. Search online for WAMP if you're using windows or XAMPP if you're using apple or any other devices (XAMPP can also run on windows). There are plenty simple tutorials about how to startup the localhost environment. For any questions you can add me in a chat (:

Answer (score 0):

You need to add a Bootstrap CDN link to your  in order to get the custom classes to work

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
 
<link hef="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
   <style>
   .center {margin: auto; }
        
    </style>   
    </head>
    
    <body>
    <div class="container">
      <div class="jumbotron" style="margin-top:20px" >
      <h1 style="color: black" class="text-center">Gord Downie</h1>
      <div class="row center">
        <img src="http://i.huffpost.com/gen/4541188/thumbs/o-GORD-DOWNIE-TRAGICALLY-HIP-570.jpg?5" class="center">
      </div>    
          <p class="caption text-center">  "He Who Walks Among The Stars" </p>


        <p class="text-center"> Gord Downie is a Canadian musician, most well known for his role as the lead singer of the Tragically Hip. More recently in his career, he has also been a spokesperson for the welfare of First Nations communities across Canada. Since 2016, Gord has been battling incurable brain cancer, but has been able to continue writing and performing. As a true artist, Gord has never let fame change him, always maintaining his focus on his music and philanthropy.</p>
        <div class="text-center">
            <h3 class="text-center"> <strong>Musical Works </strong></h3>
            <h5>As a member of the Tragically Hip:</h5>

            <ul class="text-center">
                <li>The Tragically Hip (Self-Titled) - <em>1987</em></li>
                <li>Up To Here - <em>1989</em></li>
                <li>Road Apples - <em>1991</em></li>
                <li>Fully Completely - <em>1992</em></li>
                <li>Day for Night - <em>1994</em></li>
                <li>Trouble at the Henhouse - <em>1996</em></li>
                <li>Phantom Power - <em>1998</em></li>
                <li>Music @ Work - <em>2000</em></li>
                <li>In Violet Light - <em>2002</em></li>
                <li>In Between Evolution - <em>2004</em></li>
                <li>World Container - <em>2006</em></li>
                <li>We Are the Same - <em>2009</em></li>
                <li>Now for Plan A - <em>2012</em></li>
            </ul>

            <h5>Solo Work</h5>
            <ul>
              <li>Coke Machine Glow - <em>2001</em></li>
              <li>Battle of the Nudes - <em>2003</em></li>
              <li>The Grand Bounce - <em>2010</em></li>
              <li>Secret Path - <em>2016</em></li>
            </ul>
          </div>
    </body>
</html>
```